# Why do I get a small window when I close a dialog in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython, panels

I have a `wx.Frame` that calls a `wx.Dialog`.

Now, they all work accordingly and open nicely.  The thing is that when they do, they also open a small "window" that sits on the top left corner of my frame, and after that comes out I'm unable to automatically resize  my frame with my mouse.  Closing the `dialog` has no effect, as that small window still sits there.

Inside my `wx.Frame` I have the following event call:

```
def OnTerminalSettings(self, event):
    """Open Terminal settings dialog"""
    dlg = TerminalSettingsDialog(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", settings=TerminalPanel(self).settings)
    dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()
```

and `TerminalSettingsDialog` `wx.Dialog` looks something like this:

```
class TerminalSettingsDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """Simple dialog with common terminal settings."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.settings = kwds['settings']
        del kwds['settings']
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.checkbox_echo = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Local Echo")
        self.checkbox_unprintable = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Show unprintable characters")
        self.radio_box_newline = wx.RadioBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Newline Handling", choices=["CR only", "LF only", "CR+LF"], majorDimension=0, style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_ROWS)
        self.button_ok = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "OK")
        self.button_cancel = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Cancel")

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.__attach_events()
        self.checkbox_echo.SetValue(self.settings.echo)
        self.checkbox_unprintable.SetValue(self.settings.unprintable)
        self.radio_box_newline.SetSelection(self.settings.newline)

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("Terminal Settings")
        self.radio_box_newline.SetSelection(0)
        self.button_ok.SetDefault()

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Input/Output"), wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_4.Add(self.checkbox_echo, 0, wx.ALL, 4)
        sizer_4.Add(self.checkbox_unprintable, 0, wx.ALL, 4)
        sizer_4.Add(self.radio_box_newline, 0, 0, 0)
        sizer_2.Add(sizer_4, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_3.Add(self.button_ok, 0, 0, 0)
        sizer_3.Add(self.button_cancel, 0, 0, 0)
        sizer_2.Add(sizer_3, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 4)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        sizer_2.Fit(self)
        sizer_2.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.Layout()

    def __attach_events(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOK, id = self.button_ok.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel, id = self.button_cancel.GetId())

    def OnOK(self, events):
        """Update data with new values and close dialog."""
        self.settings.echo = self.checkbox_echo.GetValue()
        self.settings.unprintable = self.checkbox_unprintable.GetValue()
        self.settings.newline = self.radio_box_newline.GetSelection()
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_OK)

    def OnCancel(self, events):
        """Do not update data, but rather close dialog."""
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_CANCEL)
```

I don't know if this is important, but the frame holds a top `wx.Panel` which in turn contains other two `wx.Panel`s.  I want to be able to have a terminal in one of such panels.

I got the code for the terminal from the [PySerial examples](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyserial/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/pyserial/examples/wxTerminal.py), so I guess they are working just fine.

Can anyone please lend me a hand?

**Addendum**

This is the code inside `TerminalPanel`:

```
class TerminalPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.serial = serial.Serial()
        self.serial.timeout = 0.5    #make sure that the alive event can be checked from time to time
        self.settings = TerminalSetup()  #Placeholder for the settings
        self.thread = None
        self.alive = threading.Event()

        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        TextPanel.text_ctrl_output = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.__do_layout()
        # self.OnPortSettings(None)  #Call setup dialog on startup, opens port
        if not self.alive.isSet():
            self.Close()


    def StartThread(self):
        """Start the receiver thread."""
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.ComPortThread)
        self.thread.setDaemon(1)
        self.alive.set()
        self.thread.start()


    def StopThread(self):
        """Stop the receiver thread, wait until it's finished."""
        if self.thread is not None:
            self.alive.clear()  #Clear alive event for thread
            self.thread.join()  #Wait until thread has finished
            self.thread = None  #Set flag as empty


    def __do_layout(self):
        """Set general layout """
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.text_ctrl_output, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dlg = TerminalSettingsDialog(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", settings=TerminalPanel(self).settings)
```

This statement is creating a new instance of `TerminalPanel` that is a child of `self` each time you create an instance of the dialog.  That is your extra window.  If you already have an instance somewhere of `TerminalPanel` then you should probably be getting the settings object from it instead of making a new one.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  How do I do that? (I'm sorry, I'm completely new at this)  --I'm attaching the code of `TerminalPanel`

Comment: Assuming the initial instance of `TerminalPanel` is created in the frame, you should save a reference to it when it is created.  Like `self.termPanel = TerminalPanel(self)` and then later in `OnTerminalSettings` you can use it like this `dlg = TerminalSettingsDialog(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", settings=self.termPanel.settings)`

Comment: Thanks @RobinDunn. The instance `TerminalPanel` is created in another `wx.Dialog` class called `TopPanel`, not the `MainWindow` `wx.Frame`.  How do I take this into consideration to set it accordingly?

Comment: I think I got it... `settings=self.top_panel.terminal_panel.settings`